# How can I pop objects from Redis as they are added realtime?

Tags: node.js, redis

I want to get a Node.js process running as it's checking a Redis server for anything new to pop.

Another process will be doing the pushing sporadically, and the Node process will be trying to pop whatever that comes in. The Node process will stay running.

Can anyone point me to a good direction?

I'm trying to figure out how to listen for such event. Sure, I can pop it once, but how do I get Node process to keep listening for any addition to Redis server?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll want to use a blocking pop: http://redis.io/commands/brpop

```
function waitForPush () {
  client.brpop(['list','otherlist',0], function (listName, item) {
    // do stuff
    waitForPush();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I'm really stuck on 'how to listen' part. I cannot wrap my head around what strategy to use. I've thought of running a while-loop, running a server, etc. Any take on that?

Comment: Blocking pops if there's anything in the lists you give it, or if there isn't it blocks the redis client until there is something to pop.

Comment: So, a possible solution is to have a recursive function to check continuously? I should try that. thanks.!

Comment: Wouldn't this eventually throw a stack overflow exception?  That's what this website is about, right?

Comment: @MattW-D I believe there will be no stack issues here because the 'recursion' happens in a callback.

Comment: @generalhenry is there a chance that any message might get lost before `client.brpop()` in recursion?

Answer (score 12):

This seems like a good use case for pub/sub: http://redis.io/topics/pubsub

Your Node.js process that sporadically pushes to Redis can also publish to a channel each time it pushes something. Like this:

```
var pushClient = redis.createClient();
//push something onto Redis
pushClient.publish("pubsub-channel", "Just pushed something onto Redis");
```

Then your other process would subscribe to that channel. Each time the message event is fired, you pop off whatever was just pushed:

```
var client = redis.createClient();
client.subscribe("pubsub-channel");
client.on("message", function(channel, message){
//pop off new item
});
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a modified version of recursive function with a process.nextTick(...)

```
function waitForPush () {
  client.brpop(['list','otherlist',0], function (listName, item) {
    // do stuff
    process.nextTick(waitForPush);
  });
}
```