# redis lists in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I want to use redis lists as a queue, where one thread pushes info in, and a separate thread processes the info as it comes in. To test this with a single thread, I created sequential examples.

This works:

```
client.lpush("trades", "100.00" );
client.lpush("trades", "$101.00" );
client.lpush("trades", "$102.00" );
client.lpush("trades", "$103.00" );
client.brpop('trades', 0, function(list, items) { console.log(items); });
client.brpop('trades', 0, function(list, items) { console.log(items); });
client.brpop('trades', 0, function(list, items) { console.log(items); });
client.brpop('trades', 0, function(list, items) { console.log(items); });
```

This doesn't give the expected output:

```
client.lpush("trades", "100.00" );
client.lpush("trades", "$101.00" );
client.lpush("trades", "$102.00" );
client.lpush("trades", "$103.00" );
while(true){
    client.brpop('trades', 0, function(list, items) { console.log(items); });
}
```

I'm thinking this might be a javascript syntax misunderstanding, but not sure.

Comment: while(true) ? This is one fine infinite loop right there!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602956/how-can-i-pop-objects-from-redis-as-they-are-added-realtime

Comment: Thanks, using the recursive function works like a charm.